# Understanding a point of the example that the Euclidean metric is a Riemannian metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry

A hint that many geometers give for people who start in Riemannian Geometry is associate the definitions of the course of Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the respectively definition in Riemannian Geometry and observe that the definitions in Riemannian Geometry are just generalizations of the definitions of the Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Following this hint and based on that I did a course of Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the Do Carmo's book, I'm trying understand how the Riemannian metric generalizes of the First Fundamental Form.

Let be $M^n$ a $n$-differentiable manifold. In this case is just consider $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ for each $i, j = 1, \cdots, n$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = e_i$ for each $i = 1, \cdots, n$, considering $e_i$ as the elements of the canonical basis of the $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ the elements of the coordinate basis of $T_pM$ for some $p \in M^n$ fixed. My doubt is how can I interpret the equality $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = e_i$? Because it doesn't seem that this equality it's true since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a derivation defined at $p$, i.e., a linear operator which take a real function defined on $M$, which is differentiable on $p \in M$, and returns $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \in \mathbb{R}$, which is not an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for every $f$ that the operator can take, while $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = e_i$ considering the trivial isomorphism between the space of derivations in $p$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ or is just an abuse of notation for something? If it is an abuse of notation, can you explain what is the abuse of notation? I really didn't understand why this equality it's true.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the identification
$$\left.\frac{d}{dx^i}\right\vert_p \leftrightarrow e_i$$
is made exactly via the canonical isomorphism $$T_p \Bbb R^n \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^n$$
defined for each $p \in \Bbb R$ (what you called the "trivial isomorphism"). This isomorphism is recorded, for example, as Proposition 3.2 (and immediately proved) in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (at least in the first edition).

In fact, such a canonical isomorphism exists if we replace $\Bbb R^n$ with any real or complex finite-dimensional vector space, but NB there is no analogue of this map for general smooth manifolds.

Comment: What you mean when you said "there is no analogue of this map for general smooth manifolds"? Because the isomorphism would be between $T_pM^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the canonical isomorphism must exist if we do the identification as you did in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I mean exactly that: For a general manifold $M$ and $p \in M$ there is no preferred identification $T_p M \leftrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ (where $n := \dim M$).